# Load Lat/Long data into QGIS layer from MSSQL Query

Tags: qgis

I'm very new to QGIS.

I have a table with lat long data stored as text, which I can save as a .csv and load in as a Delimited Text Layer and it shows up just fine.
I'm now trying to load the data directly from my MSSQL database, and am struggling to find how to create a layer based on a query. Is this even possible or am I going about it the wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open [`Layer > Data Source Manager`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/getting_started.html#sample-session-loading-raster-and-vector-layers) in QGIS.
2. Go to the [tab MS SQL Server](https://%20If%20you%20open%20data%20source%20manager%20in%20QGIS,%20there%20is%20a%20tab%20MS%20SQL%20Server,%20where%20you%20can%20set%20a%20connection%20-%20see:%20docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/%E2%80%A6%20Once%20establishe%20and%20loaded%20as%20a%20layer,%20in%20the%20layer%20properties,%20there%20is%20a%20tab%20Source%20where%20you%20can%20set%20a%20Provider%20Feature%20Filter:%20fill%20in%20your%20SQL%20query%20there.): there you can create a connection to your database.

Once established and loaded as a layer, in the layer properties (right click layer > Properties), there is a tab called `Source` where you can set a [Provider Feature Filter](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#query-builder): fill in your SQL query in the Query builder.

*There is also the [DB manager plugin](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/opening_data.html#the-db-manager), but not for MSSQL databases.*

[image]